# Cannot POST nodejs

Tags: node.js, formulário, post

Estou fazendo uma aplicação nodejs e me deparei com o seguinte erro:

> Cannot POST /noticias/noticias/salvar

[image: erro]

como resolvo?

admin.js

```
module.exports = function(application){
    application.get('/formulario_inclusao_noticia', (req, res) => { 
        res.render("admin/form_add_noticia");
    });
    
        application.post('/noticias/salvar', function(req,res){
        var noticia = req.body;
                   
        console.log(noticia);
        req.assert('titulo','Título é obrigatorio').notEmpty();
        req.assert('resumo','Resumo é obrigatorio').notEmpty();
        req.assert('resumo','Resumo é deve conter entre 10 e 100 caracteres').len(10, 100);
        req.assert('autor', 'Autor obrigatório').notEmpty();
        req.assert('data_noticia', 'Data inválida').notEmpty().isDate({format: 'YYYY-MM-DD'});
        req.assert('noticia', 'Noticia obrigatório').notEmpty();

        var erros = req.validationErrors();
        console.log(erros);
        if(erros){
            res.render("admin/form_add_noticia");
            return;
        }
    
        var connection = application.config.dbConnection();
        var noticiasModel = new application.app.models.noticiasDAO(connection);

        noticiasModel.salvarNoticia(noticia, (error, result) => {
    
                res.redirect('/noticias'); 
            });
    });
}
```

noticiasDAO.js

```
function NoticiasDAO(connection) {
    this._connection = connection;
}

NoticiasDAO.prototype.getNoticias = function(callback) { 
    this._connection.query("select * from noticias", callback); 
}

NoticiasDAO.prototype.getNoticia = function(callback){
    this._connection.query("select * from noticias where id_noticia = 3", callback);
}

NoticiasDAO.prototype.salvarNoticia = function(noticia, callback) {
    console.log(noticia);
    this._connection.query("insert into noticias set ? ", noticia, callback); 
}

module.exports = () => {
   return NoticiasDAO;
};
```

form

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        
        <title>Formulario de cadastro de Notícia</title>
    </head>
<body>

    <h1>Adicionar notícia</h1>
    <br>
    <form action="./noticias/salvar" method="post">
        <label>Titulo da Noticia</label>
        <input type="text" name="titulo" id="titulo" placeholder="Titulo da Notícia">
        <br>
        <label>Detalhes da Notícia: </label>
        <textarea name="noticia" id="noticia" cols="30" rows="5"></textarea>
        <br>
        <label>Resumo</label>
        <input type="text" name="resumo" id="resumo" placeholder="Titulo da Notícia">
        <br>
        <label>Data dos Fatos</label>
        <input type="date" name="data_noticia" id="data_noticia" placeholder="Titulo da Notícia">
        <br>
        <label>Nome do Autor</label>
        <input type="text" name="autor" id="autor" placeholder="Titulo da Notícia">
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
    </form>

</body>
```

Creio que o erro se dê em algum desses dois.

Comment: Forneça a mensagem de erro completa

Comment: A url que você registrou foi `/noticias/salvar`, e você esta tentando chamar `/noticias/noticias/salvar`...

Comment: coloquei a imagem ali. eu sei que está dando algum problema com as rotas, mas não consigo identificar qual

Comment: Ao que me parece você esta repetindo o path `/noticias`

Comment: sim, estou. mas o que eu não consegui identificar foi o onde. porque isso só ocorre no envio do formulário

Comment: O problema esta no envio do seu form, e você não colocou ele na pergunta..
Coloca ai a maneira como você submete seu form

Comment: prontinho, tá ali

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118496/discussion-between-beatrice-benetti-and-giovane).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

o erro está no "action" do formulário

"./noticias/salvar" é relativo ele vai ser convertido para "{url atual}/noticias/salvar"

a solução é simples: delete o ponto, e ele se tornara uma URL absoluta:
"/noticias/salvar" que será convertido pelo browser para "{site}/noticias/salvar" (invés de "{site}/noticias/noticias/salvar")

Comment: era isso mesmo. obrigada!